# Nuxt useFetch not getting cookies when page reload

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxt3

Im trying to call an api from my express server using useFetch, it works but if I try to **reload the page**, the api doesnt get call. My guess is that the httponly cookie was not attach to the request or the cookie was not available during reload cause when I remove the checkTokenMiddleware from my express api, it works.

```
<script setup>
    definePageMeta({
        middleware: 'auth'
    })

    const {data:posts} = await useFetch(useRuntimeConfig().public.API_URL+'/api/posts', {
        credentials: 'include',
    })
</script>
```

**Express**

```
PostRoute.get('/', [checkTokenMiddleware], getAllPost)
```

a workaround is to add the server: false option in useFetch, that works, but I guess i want it to be rendered on the server also.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, ensure that your server sets `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` to be true:

```
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
```

Also, add this config to your useFetch:

```
const { data: posts } = await useFetch(url, {
  credentials: 'include',
});
```

And remember on the server, during SSR, cookies from the incoming request might not be attached to fetch automatically. To ensure cookies are forwarded to the fetch request during SSR, you might need to pass them explicitly.

Since it's not directly straightforward with useFetch, consider using serverMiddleware to check and forward the cookie during SSR.

```
if (process.server) {
  const cookie = req.headers.cookie;
}
```

And lastly, ensure the `HttpOnly` cookie is set with the right domain and path. If your API and Nuxt app are on different subdomains, set the cookie's domain accordingly to ensure it's accessible.

Hope this helps!

---

**EDIT**

Let's add some details how to use my previous answer.

So, Create a middleware ( for example `middleware/cookieForwarder.js`):

```
export default function (context) {
  if (process.server) {
    context.ssrContext.req.serverCookie = context.req.headers.cookie;
  }
}
```

Then, use it in component:

```
<script setup>
    definePageMeta({
        middleware: ['auth', 'cookieForwarder']
    })

    let serverCookie;

    if (process.server) {
        serverCookie = useContext().ssrContext.req.serverCookie;
    }

    const headers = {};

    if (serverCookie) {
        headers['Cookie'] = serverCookie;
    }

    const {data: posts} = await useFetch(useRuntimeConfig().public.API_URL + '/api/posts', {
        credentials: 'include',
        headers: headers
    });
</script>
```

In your express app (appropriate header and CORS realted settings):

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();

app.use(cors({
    origin: 'YOUR_NUXT_APP_URL_HERE', // e.g., 'http://localhost:3000'
    credentials: true
}));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
    next();
});
```

And in your route in express app:

```
res.cookie('cookieName', 'cookieValue', {
    httpOnly: true,
    domain: 'YOUR_DOMAIN_HERE',  // e.g., '.yourdomain.com' (the leading dot is for subdomains)
    path: '/'
});
```

Consider that the last part is somehow abstract since you didn't provided much details for express server. But this will do the job.

Hope this helps again!

Comment: sorry, can u give an example on this, like how do i forward the http only cookie to the server side

Comment: I've added some details.

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
onMounted(() => {
  nextTick(() => {
    useFetch('...', {})
  })
})
```

we use `onMounted` to make sure page is mounted, and use `nextTick` to make sure DOM is ready